# Javascript - a link to appear if the correct word is entered into the prompt

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, prompt

I'm making a little javascript demo and I want it to work so when you type in the correct word into the prompt box it shows a clickable link (or button) to proceed to another page (currently a placeholder link to google) along side with some text. I would like some suggestions on how to do this effectively and simply. Thanks.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me to talk to the guard</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var txt;
var colour = prompt("If you wanna get in to the castle tell me what the current king's favourite colour is");

if (colour == "red" || colour == "Red") {
txt= "well done" + <button onclick="a href="www.google.com">Click to continuue</button> <!--incorrect code to be changed-->
 } 
else {
txt="sorry you aren't allowed in";
 }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
  var txt;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the single quotes that will concatenate the `<button>` html in the `txt`. Change your code to include single quotes,

```
'<button onclick="a href="www.google.com">Click to continuue</button>'
```

**Final Code**

```js
function myFunction() {
var txt;
var colour = prompt("If you wanna get in to the castle tell me what the current king's favourite colour is");
if (colour == "red" || colour == "Red") {
txt= "well done" + '<button onclick="a href="www.google.com">Click to continuue</button>';
 } 
else {
txt="sorry you aren't allowed in";
 }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me to talk to the guard</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost right. This should work.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button')
var result = document.querySelector('#result')
button.addEventListener('click', onButtonClick)

function onButtonClick(e) {
  var toInsert;
  var color = prompt("If you wanna get in to the castle tell me what the current king's favourite colour is");

  if (color.toLowerCase() === "red") {
    toInsert = 'Well done!\n\n <a href="www.google.com">Click to continue</a>'
  } else {
    toInsert = "sorry you aren't allowed in";
  }
  result.innerHTML = toInsert;
}
```

```html
<button>Click me to talk to the guard</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```